# Effect of the surjectivity of Galois representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $K$ be any arbitrary number field and $E$ be any elliptic curve over it. For any integer $m,$ consider the well-known Galois representation
$$\rho:\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)\to \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}),$$
given by the action on $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ on $E[m].$ Then we know from Weil-pairing that $\zeta_m\in K(E[m])$ and $\sigma(\zeta_m)=\zeta_m^{\det(\rho(\sigma))},$ where $\zeta_m$ is the primitive $m^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. Now suppose that $\text{im}(\rho)=\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}).$ Then isn't it true that the fixed field of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ correspond to $K(\zeta_m)$?

Comment: Yes. Let $L$ be the fixed field. Then $\rho$ restricted to the absolute Galois group of $L$ has trivial determinant, but that determinant is the cyclotomic character of $L$, so $K(\zeta_m) \subset L$. Now compare degrees.